# Moving wire in uniform magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

When a wire moves in a uniform magnetic field, so do its electrons. If electrons move in a magnetic field, Lorentz's force will act on them. Two sides of the wire will become polarized. We know that Lorenz's force is always perpendicular to velocity so can we say that they accumulate on the sides of the wire doing circular motion?[image]

Comment: Yes, and this produces a [motional emf](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-physics/chapter/23-3-motional-emf/).

Comment: Often Ludvig Valentin Lorenz (Lorenz condition) and Hendrik Antoon Lorentz (Lorentz force) are confused.

Comment: If you connect the wire to an electrical load, your setup is essentially an electrical generator.